# Not able to apply PrimeNG styles to non PrimeNG components

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am learning angular for a personal project and a friend of mine suggested me to use PrimeNG. I started trying some of the components and the examples so far seemed to work fine but when I tried to use a dark theme the background was not changing.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="p-col-6 p-offset-3 p-shadow-1">
    <p-steps [model]="items"></p-steps>
</div>
```

And I loaded the Theme, as they say in their [guide](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup), by editing `angular.json`. I have chosen the theme Vela blue.

The theme is being applied properly to the p-steps element. The size of the div and shadow look right, so the classes are applying. The problem is that it is just applying those styles, not the blue dark background color or the rounded borders. I would like to apply the theme to my full webpage (as they do on their webpage) but I am not sure how I should do it.

Thanks.

EDIT:
It looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: Hi, I read theming guide and dind't find something especial. It looks like PrimeNg doesn't provide ready themes, it describes how you can create your own theme. Anyway, I think you can get answer faster if you joined to PrimeLand discord server - https://discord.gg/gzKFYnpmCY

Comment: can you share a screenshot of  your problem all free theme are ready theme for all project

Comment: I just edited the question with pictures